# Тире или всё же запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Я легко понимаю, что в этом предложении надо обязательно тире.

`Сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте – вопрос трудный.`

Я, однако, сомневаюсь насчёт того, тире – я думаю, что тире, – или же всё же то запятая нужна, если мы сделаем перестановку.

`1. Трудный вопрос – сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте.`

`2. Трудный вопрос, сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте.`

Comment: «Я легко понимаю, что **в этом предложении надо обязательно тире.**

_Сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте – вопрос трудный._» ===  **Нет, не обязательно тире. Можно поставить и запятую**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте – **вопрос трудный**.*

(2) ***Трудный вопрос** – сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте.*

**Пояснение**

*Сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте – это  вопрос **(какой?)** трудный.* **Определительные отношения**. Сравнить: *Заданный вопрос – вопрос трудный. Заданный вопрос является трудным.*

*Это трудный вопрос (**какой именно**?) – сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте.* **Пояснительные отношения**. Сравнить: *Трудный вопрос – заданный вопрос. Трудным вопросом является заданный вопрос.*

**Вывод**: В обоих случаях надо ставить **тире** как более сильный знак, но не запятую.

**Примечание.** Если говорить о структурной грамматике, то у нас в **простом** предложении на месте **подлежащего или сказуемого** находится целое **предложение** (*сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте*).  Но знаки при этом ставятся по обычным правилам: **тире** между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: А вы в курсе, что скоро новые правила выйдут? Даже будет общественное обсуждение, это очень круто. https://nplus1.ru/blog/2022/04/11/orthoreform2

Comment: Я слышала об этом,  но углубляться в эту тему нет желания. Общественному осуждению я не особо доверяю. Поговорят, а потом примут то, что решили. Тогда и будем думать, кто виноват и что делать.

Comment: Не думаю, что они будут принимать какие-то неправильные решения. Хотя в справочнике Лопатина одна бредовая вещь есть. Обсуждение прежде всего для того, чтобы закрыть пробелы. Это нужно, чтобы знающим и без правил не приходилось долго спорить и доказывать. Надо составить список того, чего нет в правилах, и отправить им. Как вам идея?

Comment: Нет, не хочу составлять))   Не вижу пользы, даже не прочитают.

Comment: Не, ну сказано же, что вынесут на общественное обсуждение. Не знаю, в каком формате...

Comment: В 1990-х годах перед комиссией была поставлена задача повторить труд, сделанный в 1956 году: провести полную ревизию накопившихся вопросов и подготовить новый всеобъемлющий компендиум орфографии и пунктуации, на который могли бы опереться те, кто пишет, читает и редактирует. Завершить эту работу, по словам Левонтиной, планируется в 2023 году, когда будет создан **специализированный сайт свода**. «Эта работа идет, это будет фундаментальный интернет-портал, где полностью будут описаны правила русской орфографии и пунктуации», — говорит она. Это круто!

Comment: В качестве решения проблемы комиссия предлагает признать наиболее авторитетным сводом правил правописания не сокращенный, а полный текст Полного академического справочника, а также **разработать механизм обновления правил**. Круто!

Comment: Будем наблюдателями, спасибо за информацию. Интересно!

Comment: Ещё же есть стилистические и логические ошибки, их даже больше, чем орфографических и пунктуационных. Разобраться с этим для них, наверно, вообще что-то неподъёмное.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем решить задачу **другим способом** (синтаксическая синонимия).

Заменим заданное предложение сложноподчиненным предложением (СПП).

(1) ***Как бы я сделал** – я не знаю.* Здесь союзное слово КАК БЫ

Изъяснительное придаточное на первом месте, в этом случае рекомендуется **тире.**

(2) Я не знаю, **как бы я сделал.** Я не знаю – **как бы я сделал.**

Если придаточное **нераспространенное**, то в СПП ставится запятая.  Тире допускается при увеличенной паузе. Если придаточное **распространенное**, то в СПП лучше поставить тире, хотя запятая возможна.

Это решение применяем  к заданному предложению. Вариант(1) – **только тире.** Вариант  (2) – **тире** как основной знак, а **запятая** допускается.

Но решение было сделано для СПП, а у нас **бессоюзная** связь.В этом  случае требуется **более сильный** знак, а именно **тире**.

Итак, решения **разные**, а вывод одинаковый: **ставится тире.**

1. *Сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте – **вопрос трудный.***

(2) ***Трудный вопрос** – сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте.*

P.S. **Сомнения** в этой теме понятны: **изъяснительные** отношения здесь присутствуют, а их можно обозначить тире или запятой. При подчеркнутой паузе ставится **тире** (нейтральный стиль), а разговорном стиле возможна **запятая** (произносительная пауза).

Comment: С первым пртмером согласен. А можно ли во втором поставить двоеточие? Здесь сложное предложение, где можно поставить союз А ИМЕННО. В таких случаях, как правило, можно ставить двоеточие

Comment: Два варианта? Трудный вопрОс (какой именно?): сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте. ТрУдный вопрос (какой именно?) – сделал я бы так же или по-другому-таки на твоём месте. Интересное замечание, и вот я стараюсь  разобраться: что лучше походит? Знак зависит от ударения. При двоеточии у на интонационное предупреждение (трудный вопрОС), а при тире ударение на первом слове (трУдный вопрос).